# close-reason suggestion: closing a question where the asker wants others to do his homework

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was going over close votes, when I stumbled into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629429/ssrs-column-chart). Notice it was put on hold because:

> **unclear what you're asking**
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's
>   currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
>   the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Only this isn't *entirely* true. While the question is kinda not-specific, it is quite clear. The way I see it, the problem is he's not asking something specific but kinda asking "hey can you solve this for me?" (as one commenter very nicely puts it `"Please always include things you've tried and researched"`).

And this isn't an isolated case, I [constantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611042/can-you-help-me-to-solve-this) [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340920/can-help-me-to-solve-listview?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048025/false-mirrors-can-you-help-me-to-solve) where the bottom line is "[This is my homework, can you solve it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794940/how-to-write-the-sorting-on-a-singly-linked-list-in-c)". I think it'll be good if off-topic will have another option, quoting the [on-topic help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem
>   being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and
>   how it should work

[Here's a case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385716/upload-image-or-file-with-jquery-function-just-with-it-no-php-no-more-codes-need) where this was actually used (I'm guessing it either used to exist or that multiple voters used it in their comment as a special close vote). I know it might be a tad insulting for new users, but sometimes I feel like it's really necessary.

Maybe if we change the phrasing a little, it would be better suited. What do you think?

**small update**

I just went over close votes and [saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960147/writing-php-data-form-to-accept-odd-number-of-words-as-sentence-then-reverse-the). It's notable because the OP actually up and posted *an entire assignment verbatim.* It was also closed as "Too Broad" (which isn't true, the assignment is very specific) so it's a good example of the problem I mentioned.

However, much more important than that is the very well-written comment left by user @MichaelBerkowski:

> When posting an assignment question, we are often happy to help you
>   where you are stuck, given evidence of a solid effort and your current
>   level of understanding of both the problem and the code you've
>   attempted to solve it with. Not many of us are likely to provide a
>   solution to an assignment problem asked in this way however

I think any the phrasing of my suggested close-reason should probably be some variation of that

Comment: That was an old close reason that is no longer available because it was being abused. I'm not sure why that text hasn't been removed from the help page yet.

Comment: @BoltClock I suspected as much, but couldn't find any relevant discussion on the subject in meta (or anywhere). I can see how it might be abused, but in some cases it's the best fitting description. I still think it belongs on the help text, and also on the off-topic options. Not abusing it is the responsibility of moderators. Also - can't we just add some message that "are you sure this is your reason to close this question?" when it's selected, or maybe limit the times it can be used per day, all to discourage abusing it?

Comment: I actually believe some of these are people who are interviewing rather than doing just homework -- As a hiring manager in many companies, I have frequently given people 45 minutes to write a program, not dissimilar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419691/how-to-put-text-file-into-structure-and-have-function-to-search-within-it -- and within a last few years I have been given pushback from people when they realize they don't have internet access when doing it.

Comment: related: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which flag options are the most suitable for question asking for codes without effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251775/which-flag-options-are-the-most-suitable-for-question-asking-for-codes-without-e)

Comment: most of the links now point to page not found be this question is still critical

Comment: @sandwood it has been 4 years, considering most of them pointed to bad questions, they were deleted. I can still see them (10k rep) but I don't think this question is important enough for me to undelete them. I'm not sure what's the best course of action here

Answer (score 20):

I support the idea of this question. Reading the words after "*unclear what you're asking*" and the help pages very carefully leads to the lack of research reason but that is so far away from the words "unclear what you're asking" as to be unhelpful. Many of these question are very clear, the asker want some code written for them, or some pointers on how to write some code.

Think also of the asker whose question is closed because it is "*unclear what you're asking*". Their question is very clear to them. They might be able to add some more details but that would not change the essence of "please write some code for me". I do not see how the "*unclear what you're asking*" reason helps the asker understand the policies on what is or is not allowed.

Comment: I also see that for some homework questions _"unclear what you're asking"_ is inapropriate. This is why I often think back and forth whether _"too broad"_ is the better flag for some of those questions. However, often neither of these two flags fit well. Choosing the correct flag shouldn't be ambiguous, because it makes consistent flagging difficult.

Answer (score 8):

Finding an appropriate close reason for a "do my homework" question Isn't that hard.

- If they tell you what the assignment is, but they either don't ask a question about it, or ask for vague "advice", the problem is that as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what they're asking.  Because of that, you should vote to close as **Unclear what you're asking**.
- If they're straight up asking you do their project for them, the problem is that there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.  Because of that, you should vote to close as **Too Broad**.

If you both understand the question, and don't think that the question is asking for too many things, and if it's not closeable under any other close reason, then you should really re-consider whether the question really needs to be closed.

Comment: What bugs me is that it's plenty clear what they're asking and what they're asking for is quite narrow.  It's just unspeakably lazy and it wastes everyone's time.  (I guess it would be fitting to click on a random close reason instead; if they're too lazy to do their homework, I can be too lazy to give a proper close reason.  But that seems kinda weak.)

Comment: @tmyklebu It's not narrow at all.  The question that was linked was asking at least 3 different questions  he even numbered them himself, and it was likely asking more.  Even a simple homework assignment such as `"Take 2 numbers from the user and print their sum"` is asking you how to 1.  Take input from the user,  2.  sum the numbers, and 3.  print output.  That's 3 different questions.  Definitly too broad

Comment: I don't buy it.  You can decompose almost all good questions into "multiple" questions like that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406069/how-does-excel-evaluate-fact170-fact169-correctly is plenty narrow enough, but you could say it's asking (1)  why the representation of 170! is good enough, (2) why the representation of 169! is good enough, and (3) why the quotient rounds to 170.

Comment: Compare with version 1 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437686/child-process-runs-uptime-every-3-seconds-in-c ; this question just says "Here's my homework.  I'm not really sure how to do my homework; can you help me?."

Comment: @tmyklebu that one falls into the first category

Comment: It doesn't though.  He's asking SO to do his homework.  It's very clear.

Comment: @tmyklebu go back and look at that question.  What is the sentence in there that actually ends with a question mark

Comment: With that standard, the correct close reason then depends on the precise phrasing of the question, and I don't think that's desirable.  Go back and look at the other question I linked.  Neither of the sentences ending with question marks ask the legitimate question the broader post is driving at.  (The first is clearly "too broad" and the second is founded on assumptions that are insane.  However, the post itself conveys a good question.)

Comment: @tmyklebu good god use your common sense!  First off the example you gave is a very bad one because the OP is **definitly not** asking you to the entire assignment.  In fact it looks like he's started on the assignment, but doesn't know how to approach one of the requirements, even if you look at the first draft.  The problem with that question is that he hasn't effectively communicated that that requirement is.  It's a cut and dry case of **unclear what you're asking**.

Comment: Huh?  I am using my common sense.  The question is crap because it will benefit nobody who's worth benefitting.  But it's narrow and sufficiently well-specified that there's only one reasonable interpretation of what the poster wants.  None of the canned close reasons fit the reason why the question should be closed, regardless of your valiant attempts to shoehorn "too broad" and "unclear" into fitting the purpose.

Comment: @tmyklebu  I might not have understood the problem that well because I'm not as familiar with the technology , but if **you** were able to understand what he ask asking for, and what he was asking for also doesn't take an unreasonable amount of work, than the question is not even a problem in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that's a consistent position to take.  For whatever reason, though, I don't like the idea of SO being "rentacoder for tasks too small for rentacoder," and I want to close these sorts of questions with minimal effort.  So does the poster of this question.

Comment: @tmyklebu What makes you think it's a `rentacoder` sort of problem?  does _"child process running uptime every 3 seconds"_ sound like a complete assignment?  or does it sound like a sizable portion of an assignment?

Comment: Because it would make a good homework assignment.  It's a weirdly specific and useless thing to do, but it requires you to think and learn if you haven't done it before.

Comment: @tmyklebu so what if it's homework?  We treat homework questions the same way that we treat everything else.

Comment: Nnggh.  Context, dude.  What makes me think it's a rentacoder problem?  Because it'd make a good homework assignment.  Why's it a bad SO question?  Because it's "too localised" and it shows no effort whatsoever.

Comment: @tmyklebu First, and I'm coming from a place where I'm not entirely familiar with what the OP is asking for, but are you sure that it's something that you're not likely to need if you're not on that specific homework problem? I.E. **too localized**

Comment: @tmyklebu and second, `doesn't show effort` is another one of those false "problems"  that's really just an umbrella term people use for the real problems with the question(real problems like duplication, or lack of clarity.)

Comment: Hi Sam! Thanks for your answer. It makes a lot of sense what you're saying. I'm thinking, after reading it, that maybe there's a middle ground here. First of all - I agree with your last comment that 'doesnt show effort' is problematic for many reasons (beyond being insulting), but I'm also thinking if a user writes a clear question but without any effort (the 2nd type you mention), if they see it was closed because it's too broad - well, that could be confusing, because he wouldn't get what he did wrong, end up thinking he wrote it badly (which isn't the *real* problem). what do you think?

Comment: @tmyklebu you mentioned `"I want to close these sorts of questions with minimal effort. So does the poster of this question"` - well, not exactly. I really appreciate you rallying to my cause and you raise some very good points in your comments, but I don't want to close question with minimal effort on my part. What I want is that users (especially new ones!) that show no effort understand what they did wrong without (a) outright insulting them (which happens quite often) and (b) not closing their questions with a confusing reason they don't get (even if it makes sense to us).

Comment: @yuvi  The effort put into a question is not important.  It is the **result** of that effort that is important.  So if someone asks a question that is clear, concrete, on topic, not a duplicate, but at the same time shows no effort, that it is still a **good** question, and not a candidate for closure

Comment: I don't think you're getting my point - I'm talking about bad questions - I'm saying that even if the close reasons you mentioned fit, the users who posted the questions can get confused because they address a technical issue - take the second example you mention, someone asking to straight up do his homework for him. Let's say he is not doing it out of laziness, he did try solving it, but he didn't share that information, and the *result* is a lazy question. He then sees it was closed because it's "too broad", which is both not true and wouldn't help him understand what he needs to better it

Comment: Also, I do think there's a minimal effort expected of someone asking a question, regardless of the end result. Not as much as [this guy says](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2387772) there should be, but still. It makes sense to me. I want to help people who want to help themselves and learn something along the way, not just anyone.

Comment: @yuvi  I'm afraid that I don't understand you, one one hand, you say that you're talking about bad questions, but then you turn around and say you're talking about clear questions that are not too broad.  This is making me confused.  Which kinds of questions are you concerned about.  Clear and not too broad question?  or bad questions?

Comment: @SamIam Let's take one of the questions I linked - the one where he outright [asks others to do his work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794940). If you read his comments, you can see he's not doing it out of laziness - he has bad English, sure, but he also mentions he's been trying to solve the problem for two days and has no idea what to do next. You claim this should be closed as "too broad" - but for the OP that's meaningless. He won't know how to fix the question, because for him there's nothing too broad here (he doesn't think about the number of possible answers)

Comment: [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729948/recursive-python-program-to-flatten-a-list) I just stumbled into - it's very well written - it isn't too broad and it isn't unclear. But it's also apparent that this is homework and the way he phrases the question it's obvious he expects others to work for him. Now this one happens to be a duplicate, but it just might as well not be.

Comment: @yuvi well, if it's not a duplicate, then don't close it

Comment: @SamIam even if it's clearly homework assignment?

Comment: @yuvi absolutely!  We **do not** treat homework differently than other kinds of work.

Comment: @SamIam Well, I'm not sure I agree with you on that. I usually want to see at least *some* effort from the OP to deal with the problem himself (even an "I tried and tried but couldn't" is ok. I like helping people who failed, not people who haven't even tried)