# Which flag options are the most suitable for question asking for codes without effort?

Tags: discussion, flags

From the title , some questions are asking for code , full example without effort.

Example :

1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218387/how-to-get-direction-programmatically-using-gps-in-android

2.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240689/how-to-mute-sound-in-webrtc

Which from these four flag options is the most suitable for this kind of questions

1.**unclear what you're asking**

2.**Too Broad**

3.**Off-Topic** - Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

4.**Off-Topic** - This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

The reason I'm asking is because these kind of questions are marked closed for different reasons. Sometimes it's too broad , unclear what you are asking , or off-topic. And when I flagged them , sometimes I got my flag declined Xb

**Expectaions** : If possible , after this discussion we should make this a standard for questions asking for full code tutorial like the one in my example.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Downvote and move on. Questions without effort are not off-topic, just bad. **Some** may be *Unclear what you're asking* or *too broad* as you cannot figure out what help they need.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But moderators often close it with one of these for reasons. I think we should make some standards for these kind of questions not to be on stackovrflow. Or do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'd go for off topic: `include a minimal example in the question itself`

Comment: **"PLZ BEFORE GIVING NEGATIVE VOTE KINDLY MENTION THE REASON."** Pure gold.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years: Effort would have *helped avoid* closing a question, but it is not the lack of effort itself that is the reason to close it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It does says: **Don't ask about...** Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!). So it doesn't belong here!!

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years: I'll link you to [Should Stack Overflow be awarding "A"s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840)

Comment: Whilst lacking code doesn't make a question to broad (or unclear), I find it is often the case. Having code usually dramatically reduces the scope of a question, because otherwise it can be very hard to tell how basic an explanation needs to be. It's all very well giving someone a snippet that will solve their basic php question until they reply "so does this go in my <script> tag?" (that second question is a perfect - albeit terrible - example). EDIT: urgh I appear to have misread the question, I thought you were asking about lacking code... it still vaguely applies if effort = making a start

Comment: @OGHaza I must still say that , most of the questions about "how can I do x using y" has been asked on stackoverflow. For me , everything that is **Logically** possible can be solved using google search for stackoverflow , msdn questions. Therefore , questions here should be about errors that may come across if there isn't on google before. So for analysis of errors , we need background , or we call that effort.

Comment: @Poomrokc, don't need to convince me, I've never asked a question before :p

Comment: @OGHaza o_o Then you miss half of the sites fun. :p

Answer (score 9):

To address the two questions you linked to first:

1. is too broad; it's not about effort here, but about the scope of the answers.
2. is unclear what the OP is asking. Effort would have helped clarify the question.

Generally speaking, *lack of effort* does not make a post off-topic. Lack of effort lowers the question quality (making it worthy of a **downvote**; [close votes are not super-downvotes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)!).

That said, if an OP has put in more effort into solving an issue themselves, then that effort helps narrow down a question, clarifying where they need help to complete their task. As such, a question without effort can often be closed as too broad or unclear; you need to determine this by what is required to answer the post.

See [Should Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort) as well.

Comment: Having just recently earned the privilege of close votes, I'm seeing _a lot_ of "Unclear what you're asking" votes on questions that are perfectly clear - though bad - questions. I feel like the help text in the close vote queue should explicitly mention this case.

Comment: I feel that users asking "Can you produce code that does ::insert requirement here::" is not a worthy SO question. (and may be wrong about that?) It is still not clear to me which is the best flag to raise for moderator attention.

Comment: @Paul: just downvote such questions. They are not off-topic for that reason alone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've been trying to figure out how to handle such "workorder" questions. You say downvote, but it seems that another mod disagrees: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270903/how-to-reduce-and-quickly-close-questions-that-are-merely-requirements

Comment: @River: I don't think we disagree at all. I recommend voting as *Too broad* in my answer, Robert does the same. I *also* recommend a downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, thank you! I think your comment "downvote and move on" lead to my confusion, but perhaps I took it out of context. In any case, now I have an exact answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Questions asking for full code without effort should be down-voted. IMHO