# Another homework question problem

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It comes from this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/30378538/4615177

When I look at it, I want to flag it as the user has asked for a solution to a problem because he doesn't have the time to do it himself. It's most likely being down voted for that very reason.

The question is not perfect, it could do with some clarification, but it could be salvaged. It's not too broad or unclear to be eventually answered with some feedback from the user. However after the user's deadline, will there be any feedback and will this question just die?

Most questions like this on meta state that insufficient research by the questioner is enough for "Off Topic" (see [close-reason suggestion: closing a question where the asker wants others to do his homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250867/4615177)). But since he has obviously spent time on the work as a whole, does this apply?

The main question here is, should I flag it and if so, what with?

Comment: This seems to fall under the confusion around what 'unsalvagable' and 'Could be improved' means. My current understanding is that if you want action from the user, it should be closed via the 'unsalvagable' option.

Comment: _It's not too broad or unclear to be eventually answered with some feedback from the user._  So why not ask for clarification from the user to try and improve it. If it doesn't fit a flag, then why flag it?  Just because it's homework, doesn't automatically make it off-topic.

Comment: @bluefeet the OP has already made it clear that there is not enough time for 'improvement'.  It's off-topic because the only reason it's 'not working' is that the OP does not have enough time to write another complete subsection that reads equation data from some mysterious '.dat' file of unknown origin and format.  We would have to take apart the code/data, (with its non-English names]. before even attempting to load up the dynamic texboxes that are added to 'this.panel1'.  Myself, I would have used loads of invisible design-time boxes and make them visible as required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you think it's too broad?  It looks too broad to me.  He's just laid out some high level requirements (load the data from a file into the UI) and said, "Go do the whole thing".  There's no problem to solve here.  Trying to explain *everything* about how to do this, with no focus on what the problem is, is way too broad of a question.

It also seems *very* unclear.  It says that he wants to know how to load data from his file and display it, but as we have no idea how he's storing his data, and what his UI is like, there's nowhere near enough information for us to know how to accomplish that.

The fact that the user spent a bunch of time writing code do some other work isn't relevant here at all.  He's asking us how to load data from a file and display it in his UI, which is something that he hasn't even attempted to do, and as a result has no problem with his attempts for us to work to resolve.  He has spent no time trying to solve the problem *that he's asking about*, nor done any research on how to do it.  Spending time working on other problems unrelated to what he's actually asking about is meaningless in the context of this question.

Comment: Yes, the SO question is INTENSELY ANNOYING.  How can anyone expect any help with building a complete subsection of a GUI app with no actual form, no data, no environment, no file format, no filespec etc etc.  That, and the attempt by the OP to push a time contraint onto unpaid SO contributors.  Sod it, I would CV but it's already on hold, and the 'member for 5 days' has next-to-no points to downvote away:(

Comment: @MartinJames [The user recently re-asked it, word for word, using a new account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382985/filling-dynamic-textboxes-from-dat-file) if you're still trying to find something left to do.

Comment: OK - DCV applied to the clone as well.