# Are questions relate to Linux shell off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close

I have recently gained privileged for close vote queues. So while reviewing I came across many questions tagged with **Linux** and **Shell** marked as off topic. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413927/bash-4-4-0-causes-nano-to-fail-with-received-sighup-or-sigterm) is the link for one of them.

Most of these questions are marked as off-topic. To me they seems on topic . So what should be the appropriate action for this.

Comment: What part of that question looks programming-related to you?

Comment: Are these questions programming related? Yes: keep; no: close (or vote to migrate to super user).

Comment: @CodyGray linux commands.

Comment: In what way are Linux commands related to programming? Are Windows commands also related to programming? Does that mean OS/2 questions are on-topic here?

Comment: @Cody Gray I am asking whether they are  related or not . I saw it relating to git commands context, so that's why wanted to clear my doubts

Answer (score 7):

This has always been a bit of a grey area. My rule of thumb is this

## The question is about writing a shell script

These can be on-topic. You need to be as specific as possible and keep it focused on things like syntax. BUT there's a some overlap of this with...

## The question is about general shell or Linux usage

We have a LOT of sites that can help you with this. Seriously. And those places are better because they're more focused on this type of subject and not as busy

- [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com)
- [Unix.SE](//unix.stackexchange.com)
- [Super User](//superuser.com)
- [Server Fault](//serverfault.com)

Understand that a lot of people just don't bother reading anyways and will ask it here because... why not? And a lot of people will just answer them because... why not? And still more people will close them as off-topic because they are.

## TL;DR

If you're not sure, ask on one of the specific sites mentioned above, where they are a far better fit and less likely to be closed. You CAN ask them on SO, but you have to walk a tightrope of rules to do so. (see also [Free us from the cycle of [kali-linux]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331586/free-us-from-the-cycle-of-kali-linux) )

Comment: Well your suggestions are good but I am not the one asking these questions. This are from the close vote review queues

Answer (score 5):

There's a simpler way to tell whether a shell-related question is on-topic for Stack Overflow:

If the question mentions **the commands they used** and **there *isn't* a clear link to which shell environment they're using**, or **if there's no correlation to an executable script that they're authoring**, then it's safe to presume that the question is off-topic for SO.

In the context of the question you've linked, here's the telltale signs:

> when i do the following set of commands:
>
> Everything works, when I replace bash binary 4.3.30 with compiled 4.4.0, nano fails with error message:
>
> I believe this a bug in bash and I would like to see if the hive mind has any suggestion (other than reporting the bug).

From this, I infer that the OP is using Bash as a general power user as opposed to a programmer.

In other words, in order for a question to be suitable for Stack Overflow, it needs to be specific to programming. Since this question is not about using Bash *in the context of programming*, so it is off-topic.

Comment: So according to you the current question will be on topic or off topic ?

Comment: I'm fairly confident I gave my assertion above, albeit implicitly.  Since it's not about programming, it's not on-topic for SO, although it *could* see a second life on Unix and Linux.

Comment: I made your assertion a bit less implicit. Hopefully that doesn't put words in your mouth (or at least maybe you like the taste of those words). You might want to integrate the reference to [Unix.SE] into your answer, though.

Comment: @CodyGray:  No, that seems appropriate.  I suppose I'm more implicit with these things than I should be.

Comment: Oh, I would normally be the same way. I don't understand how this is so confusing for people, but apparently it is, so it's important to spell it out. Programming Q&A site means we only want programming related questions!