# What shell utility questions are on-topic and which are off-topic on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

Whether a question about using a shell utility gets downvoted and closed, or accepted and answered on StackOverflow seems entirely arbitrary. For example, questions about how to use:

- `cut, paste, join, sort, uniq, ...` are answered as OK
- E.g. [Command 'cut' doesn't show last column CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330884/command-cut-doesnt-show-last-column-csv)

On the other hand, questions about:

- `cp, mv, scp, rsync, ssh, ...` are downvoted and closed.
- E.g. [Copy and Rename folder with a user prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326854/copy-and-rename-folder-with-a-user-prompt)

This is not a duplicate of [Are questions relate to Linux shell off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354123/are-questions-relate-to-linux-shell-off-topic). In fact the closed question above would qualify as valid according to that Meta-post because it seeks help on creating a script to automate the process, while the SO post above related to `cut` is clearly limited to *"How do I use `cut`?"*

So how are members with close vote privileges supposed to know which questions are OK to ask *"How do I use `utility_abc`?"* and which questions should be closed as off-topic when asked *"How do I use `utility_xyz`?"*. Is there a list somewhere of `utility_abc` that are valid to ask about and which `utility_xyz` are off-topic? The resulting answering as OK or downvoting/closing as off-topic seems horribly arbitrary. The [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and related links do not provide any clarity in this regard.

And, honestly, I just feel bad for those people who have there questions downvoted to oblivion and closed as off-topic, when looking at a similar *"How do I use xyz?"* question that has just been accepted and answered. All the more true when they ask *"Why has my question been closed?"* and I have no measuring stick to go by and no link to refer them to to tell person A why their question was closed?

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) tells them that questions about any of the *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* are OK, while failing to provide any demarcation or guideline on what would constitute *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic"*. From my observation over the past 5-years that leaves it up to an "I know it's off-topic when I see it..." standard that is applied in wildly differing ways with wildly differing results -- even for questions about the same shell utility.

So how does one know if the question about *"How do I use shell utility_abc?"* is OK, or whether it should be closed as off-topic?

Comment: Maybe it's the flavor of question posed.  The difference between the first and the second one is that the first question has a concrete problem defined, with (some) demonstrated effort.  The second one has a concrete problem defined with no demonstrated effort.

Comment: Yes, that was there (and why I voted to close that one) but not entirely the point of this question. The [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) standard is workable. The question here is more "All things being equal -- what `utilities_abc` are valid to ask about and what `utilities_xyz` are not?" I was trying not to focus on other aspect and just look at the utility -- there are many, many instances where that is what it falls down to and more guidance there, a list, or something to point to and say ON or OFF topic to would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell utility questions are on topic if and only if they are presented as part of a (unique) programming problem.

The key difference should be that the task to be performed with the shell utility is one of the following

- needs to repeated
- needs some logic applied
- takes input
- collects output
- handling of exceptions
- be part of script

on top of what the core function of the utility is.

If none of the above is eminent from the question then it is more likely to be a general computing question and can be closed as such.

Keep in mind that due to the nature of being a developer we all happen to be above average computer users and therefor you are likely to find someone on SO that knows the answer to most general computing questions. The expert would have to switch off their helping reflex and redirect those question to the appropriate site (I think Super User, Ask Ubuntu, Linux & Unix and Seasoned Advice, to name a few).

Comment: Ummm, "Seasoned Advice" - like "For Professional and Amateur Chefs"? Looking forward to read "How to use `strip` to peel my potatoes".