# Is a specific Docker networking issue really about "general-purpose software"?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope

Someone voted to close [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846730/docker-linux-networking-connection-reset-by-peer-despite-port-forwarding) on the grounds that it is "about general computing" software, which according to the Stack Overflow policy is discouraged unless the question "directly involve[s] tools used primarily for programming."

Does my question really fall under that umbrella? If so, could someone please explain in what sense Docker is general computing software and does not directly involve programming?

I could understand if I was merely pulling a Dockerfile off the shelf and having issues running it. But I am the one writing the Dockerfile for a specific purpose (namely, I am trying to containerize my Clojure development environment...which is pretty darn directly related to programming if you ask me).

Comment: It's a single close vote, no need to post on Meta yet. Post here if your question actually gets closed with that reason.

Comment: @Stijn:  [As far as Meta is concerned, this seems like *impeccable* timing.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380587/why-are-there-so-many-questions-closed-as-off-topic-but-they-have-many-upvotes/380589?noredirect=1#comment673105_380590)

Comment: The fact that you use docker to setup a programming environment, doesn't really make docker itself a tool that is primarily use for programming. Questions involving network problems are more a superuser/serverfault thing in my opinion.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that some Docker questions can clearly be on-topic here, and would also be on topic on Super User or Server Fault SE sites. In this case, I don't know. I don't want to go further than a simple comment, but this seems (to me) much more a network problem than a programming tool (docker) problem. I can relate to the close-voter, but I'm no expert in docker, I may be blatantly wrong, so I'll just skip this, if it was in a review queue.

Comment: Note that the fact that you have an issue trying to do something programming-related doesn't make the issue on-topic here. The issue is it has to be _unique to software development_ as explained in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If someone can reasonably have the same issue doing something that isn't programming-related, it's off-topic here and often gets categorized under the _general computing_ close reason.

Comment: @ErikA and MarkRotteveel Don't be pedantic. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357570/1394393 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330582/1394393 The only reason you'd ever set up a Docker environment is in support of application development or deployment.

Comment: @jpmc26 Note the _or deployment_ there. That's not necessarily on topic on SO. Also, I haven't cast a close vote, because I'm not sure it's off-topic. I just don't agree with the reasoning used to justify it being on-topic.

Comment: @ErikA Ever heard the term "devops"? That whole field is about blurring the line between managing environments (including production) and development. Deployment to the production environment is a fundamental concern that developers have to build for, and that fact is the major reason why Docker even got popular in the first place. Docker is clearly a tool used primarily for the purpose of developing and maintaining software. The idea that deployment is some kind of "non-programmer" concern is hogwash.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yup, and I've heard you can ask DevOps questions on [devops.se].

Comment: @ErikA [DevOps.SE] *Beta* doesn't even have a topic definition yet. lol https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15/5129 Deployment is not a non-programming concern, and tools that exist to help smooth out the process of ensuring code works in production are definitely programmer tools.

Comment: Yes, but it exists because there are DevOps questions that are not on-topic here. The point is, as said in my first comment, that the issue might not be _unique_ to software development (it might also be applicable to deployment) and that might make it off-topic. You haven't addressed that at all.

Comment: @ErikA No, it exists because someone thought it might be valuable to have a dedicated site. I addressed the idea of why "unique" doesn't mean "exclusively" in both of the posts I linked to you originally. As I said, that's pedantic. Notably, the OP's question is *explicitly* about setting up their development environment using [Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel#features), which is a Clojure server designed specifically for live front end development.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not knowledgeable enough to know if this issue is _unique_ to setting up a development environment, or just a general Docker networking issue that has a solution that might be of benefit to non-programmers.

Comment: I deleted the trail end of an extended discussion that had veered off into unproductive territory. Folks, I know it's Meta, but **comments just don't work well for extended discussions. If you want to make your point of view heard, please post an answer.**