# Which Stack Exchange site should users with 'Windows Administration' questions add their questions to?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have seen multiple downvotes to Windows administration type questions on Stack Overflow. If these questions don’t belong in Overflow, which Stack Exchange site should they be included in?

Comment: Business environment -> https://serverfault.com;
Consumer environment -> https://superuser.com

Comment: Related on meta.SE: [Where's the Stack Exchange for Windows administrators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293490/756727)

Comment: Possibly relevant, especially since PowerShell is now multi-platform and increasingly system agnostic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350392/here-is-x-part-of-any-program-ever-how-do-i-get-change-this-in-powershell

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Business/enterprise-grade questions about infrastructure and software go to [Server Fault](//serverfault.com), and consumer-grade topics of the same go to [Super User](//superuser.com). Note that **questions about dev tools and other software commonly used in the software development lifecycle** are welcome here *to a point*, especially when it comes to scripting questions. And sometimes, even if it's on topic, you might have a better audience at one of the other two sites.

For example, we'll gladly help users with running commands over WinRM/PSRemoting, questions about using and configuring the git client, etc. But trying to diagnose the Kerberos problem which is making your PSRemoting command fail hard, or asking for assistance with why Bitbucket won't start is getting out of the programming realm of things and doesn't really belong here.

Comment: If you have a link to the question I can look and suggest why it wasn't well received.

Comment: Just to put things in perspective, When I asked this question, it was voted down. Down votes are getting out of control, and I think there needs to be some new rules. They aren't helpful on their face, and I think they could be driving people away from the platform. Just my opinion, I am just a Technoob I guess...