# Are questions about making a toolchain appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

I understand that some questions that are not directly about programming are nonetheless related and thus appropriate for Stack Overflow (e.g., help with installing a package with [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29)).  However, is there a good rule of thumb for how far this can go?

For example, I'm currently having a problem using crosstools to build a toolchain.  Should I take that to Super User or is it okay here?

Comment: I voted to close this here because I just answered a very similar question but the answer will be verbatim. [Here is a link to my other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411401/which-stack-exchange-site-should-users-with-windows-administration-questions-a).

Comment: This duplicate suggestion does not make sense at _all_.  A programming toolchain is not "Windows Administration."

Comment: Note that there is an overlap between SuperUser and Stack Overflow, some questions may be appropriate on both, and you can pick and choose (but not crosspost). A litmus test for if it's programming-related (regarding software installation and others) is _Would a non-programmer ever run into this issue or a very similar one?_. That makes it more clear it depends on _which_ toolchain, e.g. if you're on Linux and the toolchain is used to install common programs from source -> more likely Super User (or Unix & Linux), else probably Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is *"crosstools"*? [CrossToolchains](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains)? [Crosstool](http://kegel.com/crosstool/crosstool-0.43/doc/crosstool-howto.html)? [CrossTools](https://github.com/crosstools/crosstools)? [Crosstool-NG](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng)? Something else?

Comment: Why can [meta-tag:discussion] questions on meta be closed as Opinion based? Isn't that the entire point?

Comment: @MegaIng For some questions that are truly about preference it makes sense (e.g. _Is it a good idea to put contact info in your profile?_). For questions about whether something is on-topic or not, not so much, so this one should be reopened imo, or closed for a better reason (it appears the first closer thought it was a duplicate)

Comment: @ErikA even for `Is it a good idea to put contact info in your profile?` I would disagree. Even if no consensus can be reached, the pro and cons are worth the question being open.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Yes

Questions about building software primarily used by programmers (like a [toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain)), for purposes of programming (like building software), are programming problems, and are therefore on-topic here.

While there are certainly questions involving building software that are off-topic here, such as build issues compiling an upgrade to your Linux kernel as an end user, building a toolchain to be used for programming is a programming task, and thus on-topic.

Comment: Just make sure the question is *specific*, *objective*, and *answerable*.

Comment: This [help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) uses two phrases to describe questions that are on-topic: *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* and *"tools used primarily for programming"*. The latter is more to the point, and helps us weed out the opinion that [if any given tool is frequently used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69115086/1889329) it necessarily is used for programming, too.